# http 1.0 Передача текстового файла с \n multipart/form-data

Tags: c, веб-программирование, http, сокет

Передаче текстового файла (программа на си, сокеты... ). Передача как Content-type: multipart/form-data , boundary генерируется случайными символами. При отсутствие в текстовом файле переноса строк, файл передается успешно, иначе - нет
Пример набора

```
POST /..../getfile.php HTTP/1.0
Host: ....
Content-type: multipart/form-data, boundary=KWYRTBOP=<=IDOF
Content-length: 186

--KWYRTBOP=<=IDOF
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="var_file"; filename="text.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

Какой либо длинный текст.
--KWYRTBOP=<=IDOF--
```

Принимающий обработчик на php в случае присутствия /n сообщает об ошибке

Comment: Ошибка связанна с boundary ! Вот только не понятно какие символы можно использовать, а какие - нет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Граница части в multipart/form-data это последовательность [CRLF, "--", значение boundary (rfc 7578)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7578#section-4.1), при этом значения boundary формально ограничены в [rfc 2046](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046#page-22):

```
 boundary := 0*69<bchars> bcharsnospace

 bchars := bcharsnospace / " "

 bcharsnospace := DIGIT / ALPHA / "'" / "(" / ")" /
                  "+" / "_" / "," / "-" / "." /
                  "/" / ":" / "=" / "?"
```

Фактически вместо CRLF можно для некоторых серверов и только LF использовать. Другие печатаемые ascii символы в boundary, помимо явно указанных, также могут работать.

В частности, пример в вопросе работает на паре-тройке серверов, которые я проверял. Пример продолжает работать, если разбить содержимого на несколько строк.

Пример ломается, если забыть новую строку перед `--{boundary}`.